# Does every app in Apple's App Store require a website?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, iphone-developer-program

Is it true that every app published on the App Store needs its own website?

When this is the case what should I be aware of?

Can I use a blog (e.g., `myApp.tumblr.com`) or do I need my own URL (e.g.,`myApp.com`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used a blog that I mainly use for the game and it worked fine.

So yes, that should work.

Edit: Oops, to answer the actual question, no, they don't require a website in my experience. I've seen apps without website names in the App Store.